# Summation formula not affecting columns in Excel soon after over writing the data into the particular cells using POI

Tags: apache-poi, excel-formula, overwrite

After I over-write data to the Excel sheet using `POI`, the sum formula for the corresponding columns doesn't work.

But when we double click the particular values in the cell and TAB out, it takes the sum formula. Is there any way to refresh the whole excel.

I need the summation soon after over-writing the values into the Excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the [POI Formula Evaluation Documentation](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/eval.html). Once you are done making changes to the spreadsheet, you'll need to recalculate the formula evaluations, as the file format caches the last value to make loading quick.

Comment: Good, glad that solved it! Please mark the answer as accepted by clicking the tick next to it, so everyone else knows it's fixed!